# Changing result from line 2 to line 1

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net application that is made to acquire a result  from a webpage to my alertbox.

The webpage's result however is on the second line and is spaced.

I can only see half the text which is inside the alertbox since it's on line 2.

How do i change it so that the result goes to line 1?

**The webpage result is like this:**

```
1
2                       Success: 127.0.0.1 works
```

**However I want it to show up on my alertbox like this:**

```
1 Success: 127.0.0.1 works
```

I've fixed the spacing so far, but I can't fix the lines.

**Here's the code:**

```
Dim Website2 As New WebClient
    Dim WebsiteIW As String = Website2.DownloadString("http://webpage.com/" + FlatTextBox1.Text)
    If WebsiteIW.Length > 37 Then WebsiteIW = WebsiteIW.Substring(0, 37)
    While WebsiteIW.Contains("                      ")
        WebsiteIW = WebsiteIW.Replace("                     ", "")
    End While
    FlatAlertBox1.Text = WebsiteIW
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
While WebsiteIW.Contains("                      ")
  WebsiteIW = WebsiteIW.Replace("                     ", "")
End While
```

Use

```
WebsiteIW = WebsiteIW.trim
```

It's a lot faster, and will get rid of an stray newline characters.

Comment: Thank you for the second time, I can't believe I'm so bad at this

Comment: No problem -- everybody's bad until they get some experience.